# What is the function of $y at the end of an interpolation function?

Tags: r

I am learning interpolation using R. I found a code online and I am not sure about the function of **`$y`** at the end of the code. I tried to run the code with and without **`$y`** and I cannot really tell the differences.

```r
test <- approx(x, y, xout=c, rule=2) $y
```

Comment: `?approx` : approx returns a list with components x and y, containing n coordinates which interpolate the given data points according to the method (and rule) desired.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply!! How about the $y at the end of the interpolation function?

Comment: In R, you can access elements of a list using `$`, e.g. MY_LIST$ELEMENT_NAME. So if `approx` outputs a list with an element called `y`, adding `$y` at the end gives you that part of the list. In this case you want the vector `y`, not the other parts of the list that `approx` outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is one way to access elements of a list in R.

(Some more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169495/6851825 or  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32819641/6851825)

This code will produce a list of `x` values (from the `c` term we provided) and interpolated `y` values.

```
x = 1:3
y = 4:6
c = seq(1,3,by = 0.5)
approx (x, y, xout=c, rule=2)
```

The output R gives us tells us that it's a list with components called `x` and `y`.

```
$x
[1] 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0

$y
[1] 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5 6.0
```

We could examine the **str**ucture of this output by running:

```
str(approx (x, y, xout=c, rule=2)) 

#List of 2
# $ x: num [1:5] 1 1.5 2 2.5 3
# $ y: num [1:5] 4 4.5 5 5.5 6
```

If we just want the `y` part, the interpolated values, we can run `approx (x, y, xout=c, rule=2)$y` to get it. Instead of a list, this is a numeric vector.

```
[1] 4.0 4.5 5.0 5.5 6.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! I thought "$y" is some sort of trek in R.. Did not think it as the regular way to access elements under interpolation function. Thankssssss!!!!!